# Sharing mobile broadband connection through datacable on android device

Tags: networking, usb, internet, android

Okay so I baught a new android device with kitkat and I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with an LTE device connected as a mobile broadband. I do have a 3g connection on my cell though but when I was browsing through the settings of my device, there I found a USB INTERNET option for the instance. In its description it was listed that I could use my Windows Internet connection with this device. Well I was willing to share 4g speed with this device of mine and so I tried to connect my device with ubuntu in the same way. But I failed in doing so, and after hours of disappointment I'm posting this question. So if anyone knows how to share mobile broadband with my android device, then please do let me know.
and yeah Thanks in Advance. :)